# deleting a node from a link list in c ++, by comparing string values

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

Problem: i am facing problem in deleting a node, let me tell you how i am inserting in it first, i have a Student LinkList, each node have an ID(Int) and Student Name(String), and code to insert nodes in the list is this:

```
void FileHandling::readLine(char filePath[], StudentList* sl1){

ifstream read_file;
string line;
read_file.open(filePath, std::ifstream::in);

if(read_file.is_open()){
        while(read_file.good()){
            getline(read_file,  line);
            if(line.substr(0,1)!= "#" && !line.empty() ){
                //cout<<line<<endl;

                std::stringstream ss(line);
                int id;
                std::string first_name, surname;
                ss >> id >> first_name >> surname;
                std::string name = first_name + " " + surname;
                //cout<< id <<", "<<name<<endl;
                sl1->insertSort(id,name); // insert node in an alphabetic order
            }
        }
}
```

}

This is how i require to delete by getting name from user: note when i get name like "abc xyz", my `string name;` variable only contain xyz in it and skip the initial name.

```
void StudentList::deleteWN(StudentList* sl1){
//Deleting from list by getting name from user
string name;
while(true){
    cout << "Deleting: Student Name 0r press 'q' to quit"<<endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout<<name<<endl;
    if(name=="q")
        break;
    sl1->deleteWithNmae(name);
    sl1->printList();
}
```

}

```
void StudentList::deleteWithNmae(const string& name1){

// CASE 1: Deleting from an empty list
if(head == 0){
    cout<< "Node can not be deleted from an Empty List"<<endl;
}else{
// Traversing the list to find Exact Node
    Student* curr = head;
    Student* prev = 0;
    while(curr != 0){
        if(curr->name == name1){
            // node found, break the while loop
            // Never compare the name of curr node with the user input
            // i also tried curr->name.length() == name1.length() 
            //and comparing the strings but i m sure i m doing something
            // wrong here and cant find my node in any case.

            break;
        }else{
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
    // CASE 2: Node not found
    if(curr == 0){
        // always execute this code, i never able to find my node
        cout<< "Student "<<name1<<" not Found .."<<endl;
    }else{
            //CASE 3: Deleting node from the head
        if(curr == head){
            head = head->next;
        }else{
            //CASE 4: Deleteing node beyond the head
            prev->next = curr->next;
        }
        delete curr;
        size--;
    }

}
```

}

Help me out with this problem Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `std::getline(std::cin, name)` to read entire line. `cin >> name` will read text before space, and not the entire line.

Example from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
  std::string name;

  std::cout << "Please, enter your full name: ";
  std::getline (std::cin,name);
  std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's working fine, node is deleted. same problem if node containing only firstname this solution is not working on that.

Comment: is this essential for 'std::getline(std::cin, name)' to always looks for a string having spaces?

Comment: @ShahjahanKhokher `getline` will always read the entire line. I guess the problem is in inserting: `std::string name = first_name + " " + surname;` If the `surname` is empty, then the `name` will be `Nemanja ` (including space). Instead of that, do something like this: `name = first_name; if(surname.length() > 0) name += " " + surname;` to add the surname only when it is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

You already do the right thing in your insert code. The only difference here is that you have to check for "q" after you have read the first name. If it's not "q" then you can read the last name. Like this

```
void StudentList::deleteWN(StudentList* sl1){
//Deleting from list by getting name from user
string firstName, lastName;
while(true){
    cout << "Deleting: Student Name 0r press 'q' to quit"<<endl;
    cin >> firstName;
    if(firstName=="q")
        break;
    cin >> lastName;
    std::string name = first_name + " " + surname;
    sl1->deleteWithNmae(name);
    sl1->printList();
}
```

Comment: That's working fine, node is deleted. now problem is if there is no lastname this code will wait for the lastname.

Comment: Then you must do what Nemanja suggested and use getline to read the names. Obviously you have the same problem when you are inserting names.

Comment: i also like your solution, Thanks you for helping